# Apache tomcat or apache ant?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ant

I'm doing a project in java which need to import the following libraries

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
```

I have downloaded apache tomcat 8.0 and configured it in eclipse as a server. Am I doing it right?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Apache Tomcat is a servlet container. Apache Ant is a build tool. Eclipse is an IDE. Commons FileUpload is a library. This is a question about 4 unrelated things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need [apache commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/).

Comment: I've done that. And copied the zip file in /WEB-INF/lib folder of the project. Yet the error doesn't go.

Comment: If you are using eclipse unzip the artifact, you should have a .jar file. Add this file in your projet build path, to do that right click on your project and go to `Properties > Java Build Path` choose the `Libraries` tab and click `Add JARs...`. Select the JAR and your are done (rebuild the project `Project > Build` if `Build Automatically` is not set).

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. What you need is the *library* [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/). Apache Tomcat is a *webserver* and Apache ant is a *compilation tool*.

Answer (score 0):

Rather download commons-fileupload from [Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/download_fileupload.cgi) and set it as dependency library.